# Use a user defined function in an insert into

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have an scalar-valued function that takes a code of `varchar(5)` of one value and translates it to another value. I am attempting to use it in an `INSERT INTO`:

```
INSERT INTO AccountTable
(
    [CustomerName],
    [CurrencyAbbreviation]
)
SELECT 
    customers.CustomerAbbreviation,
    funAMSGetCurrency(customers.Currency)                           
FROM CustomerTable customers
```

...but get an error saying `funAMSGetCurrency` is not a built in function. Is it possible to do a translation like this?

Comment: Why are you using a version of SQL Server that has been out-of-support for years?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call a user-defined function in SQL Server, you need to include the schema, which is probably `dbo`:

```
INSERT INTO AccountTable ([CustomerName], [CurrencyAbbreviation] )
    SELECT customers.CustomerAbbreviation,
           dbo.funAMSGetCurrency(customers.Currency)                           
    FROM CustomerTable customers ;
```